# csv file upload on asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net

User need to upload 30,000 csv values, these values may contain 16 digit numbers or zipcodes.

Now our asp.net project doesn't use AJAX tool kit controls or jquery or any other 3rd party controls or open source code. This is restriction as per companies privacy policy.

So I have to come with a best way to accommodate file upload feature. This has to be versatile in regards to re-usability some thing like a custom control

This file upload feature should not be saved on the server, instead I need to read data into stream buffer and send them to UI then once user verify these values he/she'll have to hit submit thus values will be saved to DB.

what are the best ways to implement this,

- Can I make use of **System.Net.Webclient**? or
- Is there any other alternative ways by using **Async HttpHandlers**?
- Can I show **file upload progress to UI** ?

Appreciate if you could help me with proper guidence on this.

Thanks in advance
krish

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well 30,000 values of zipcode or any other 16 digit code should be uploadable normally using file control(i mean via postback).

if you have to read and show 30,000 on the UI, i presume you are at risk of freezing your UI.

Moreover if you are not on HTML5, there is no way that you can read the content on the client side, except if you fiddle around with flash.

HTML 5 file api reference
http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/filesystem/

How to read and write files with Flash(Action script)

http://www.mikechambers.com/blog/2008/08/20/reading-and-writing-local-files-in-flash-player-10/

Comment: Thank you for response on this, upload file will only contains these values which comes around 528kb. 
I dont have that flexibility to use :-(

Comment: if its only 528kb you will not have any problem uploading to server, but reading on the client is not a viable option(if not for html5 n flash) ... an upvote would help